# Interactive maps and wayfinding

Tags: ios, google-maps, maps

**I want to create a wayfinding iPhone/iPad app**

the people to be able to pull up a map and for the app to track their location and show them on the map and how to get places.

I want to draw a route between 2 locations and trace route

Is there any library or framework?

I want to show a route map between two points.

Like this:

[image: Interactive maps and wayfinding]

Comment: did you find anything that worked for you?  I'm looking for something similar for iOS or Android.

Answer (score 0):

MapKit is the native iOS framework to display maps and CoreLocation is the one to obtain the user location.

Now have you read the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/ProvidingDirections/ProvidingDirections.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH8-SW6) on Location services? They give you examples on how to get locations and how to display directions on the map.

Ray Wenderlich also has some nice tutorials on the subject. [Check them out](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21365/introduction-to-mapkit-in-ios-6-tutorial).